# How to customize the font family of shipment packing slip?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, shipment

I have already customized the pdf invoice i.e

> PdfInvoice/InvoiceChange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
>   PdfInvoice/InvoiceChange/etc/module.xml
>   PdfInvoice/InvoiceChange/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
>   PdfInvoice/InvoiceChange/registration.php

So similarly, I changed pdf **shipment** packing slip also tried but in the invoice place, I overrode AbstractPdf file but not working please tell me, anyone?

**PdfShipment/ShipmentChange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
 <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" type="PdfShipment\ShipmentChange\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf"/>
```

**PdfShipment/ShipmentChange/etc/module.xml**

```
<module name="PdfShipment_ShipmentChange" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
```

**PdfShipment/ShipmentChange/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php**

```
protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
```

Comment: In the di.xml          <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="PdfInvoice\InvoiceChange\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>

Comment: In the module.xml  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="PdfInvoice_InvoiceChange" setup_version="1.0.0">
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Comment: in the registration.php   <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'PdfInvoice_InvoiceChange',
    __DIR__
);

Comment: in the Invoice.php protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

Comment: so similarly how to do that pdf shipping packing slip font?

Comment: please attach code

Comment: @RkRathod i have edited question please check my code again

Comment: please tell me the solution

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To edit the packing list, or any other PDF docs such as invoice you need to override the files contained within

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf
```

For example if wanted to add the price to the packing list

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment"
                type="Example\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment"/>

</config>
```

Then copy the file "Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment" to your app/code file, change the name spacing to match the XML above and add the following on around line number 81

```
 // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 395;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 70;
        $feedTax = $feedSubtotal + 70;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => $feedTax,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
```

Comment: please attach this code

Comment: ok i changed the di.xml filename but it is not working

Comment: any error??????

Comment: which file you want to override ??

Comment: I am overriding AbstractPdf.php but code changes are not reflecting when i am downloading the pdf file.The generated pdf file have default styles not modified one

Comment: please tell me.Just i can override style the 'lib/internal/GnuFreeFont/FreeSerif.ttf' to 'lib/internal/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'.

Comment: If i change the core default AbstractPdf.php style then it will changed. but that is not right process. i want to override that file

Comment: abstract class not overrride

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I have already done PDF invoice i am asking default shipment PDF font family how to do that  ?